# What language is this file written in and which plotting program can graph it?

Tags: 14.04

**EDIT**

I managed to open the below file with Grace in the end, but I would like to know what "language" its written in and what other plotting programs read this language.

Thank you

PS I am brand new to linux just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
@version 50109
@default linewidth 1.5
@g0 on
@with g0
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -0.25
@    world ymax      2.50
@    view xmin 0.150000
@    view xmax 0.602214
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  bar linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick minor linewidth 1.5
@    yaxis  tick major    1.0000
@    yaxis  label "Energy error (EV/atom)"
@g1 on
@with g1
@    world xmin      0.00
@    world xmax    754.92
@    world ymin     -4.00
@    world ymax      1.00
@    view xmin 0.717657
@    view xmax 1.169872
@    view ymin 0.150000
@    view ymax 0.850000
@    xaxis  tick major  136
@    xaxis  label "Cutoff energy (EV)"
@    yaxis  label "Log10 |Energy error| (EV/atom)"
@target G0.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        16.5784258405490     
   108.459781227830        1.37706700787840     
   162.989051467077       3.431021246137789E-002
   216.282381168537       1.945370131102209E-002
   264.211994723891       7.044388309623173E-003
   316.934569634781       1.883579609511798E-003
   374.450105901206       1.072583647783176E-003
   420.610728941616       7.798143890340725E-004
   486.513947975269       5.595554691808502E-004
   539.208152497737       3.921376373909879E-004
   594.355578932754       2.913218597768719E-004
   652.441864522262       1.875952541467996E-004
   692.582915874872       1.474738464821712E-004
   754.919784783225       1.057575141203415E-004
&
@target G0.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000   2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225        2.00000000000000     
&
@target G0.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.300000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.300000000000000     
&
@target G0.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.100000000000000     
   754.919784783225       0.100000000000000     
&
@target G0.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  1.000000000000000E-002
   754.919784783225       1.000000000000000E-002
&
@target G1.S0
@type xy
   53.9491654150072        1.21954329091756     
   108.459781227830       0.138955073476815     
   162.989051467077       -1.46457659262531     
   216.282381168537       -1.71099775649645     
   264.211994723891       -2.15215671231883     
   316.934569634781       -2.72501601961201     
   374.450105901206       -2.96956882841683     
   420.610728941616       -3.10800875552859     
   486.513947975269       -3.25215685504253     
   539.208152497737       -3.40656147209213     
   594.355578932754       -3.53562692620556     
   652.441864522262       -3.72677815275828     
   692.582915874872       -3.83128499213042     
   754.919784783225       -3.97568876603266     
&
@target G1.S1
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  0.301029995663981     
   754.919784783225       0.301029995663981     
&
@target G1.S2
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000 -0.522878745280338     
   754.919784783225      -0.522878745280338     
&
@target G1.S3
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -1.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -1.00000000000000     
&
@target G1.S4
@type xy
  0.000000000000000E+000  -2.00000000000000     
   754.919784783225       -2.00000000000000     
&
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I managed to open the below file with Grace in the end, but I would like to know what "language" its written in

The language IS called Grace. It seems to me to be more a configuration or set of plotting instruction then a language (you can not execute the file; you send it to the plotter).

> and what other plotting programs read this language.

The [project page](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/projects.html) lists a lot of software that can read Grace:

> **Forks/Modifications**
>
> 1. AcGrace: the NRC Analysis Code version of Grace
> 2. GraceGTK is based on the GTK toolkit and adds some new features
> 3. QtGrace is a version of Grace based on the Qt SDK by Nokia

[xmgr](https://github.com/mlund/xmgr-resurrection) is a predecessor of grace that got resurrected. But you probably will be better of with Grace itself.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I understand more clearly, I did realise it was simple plotter instructions but had failed to have any program on windows plot the results (without manually extracting them). I appreciate your patient help